# Creating neat .csv file from a giant dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have created dictionary from ESPN's API with a bunch of data I need, and it is all neat and organized. I need this data in .csv for my friend to do machine learning on it, but I do not know where to begin.

Here is my code that formats the data from the API into dict data

NOTE: I have print(data) at the bottom which is temp and to help whoever runs it.

```
import requests

root_link = "http://sports.core.api.espn.com/v2/sports/football/leagues/nfl/seasons/2022/types/2/weeks?lang=en&region=us"
response1 = requests.get(url=root_link)
weeks = response1.json()
data = {}
for i in range(16):
print(f"========= WEEK {i + 1}/16 =========")
week_link = weeks\["items"\]\[i\]\["$ref"\]

    response2 = requests.get(url=week_link)
    week_data = response2.json()
    get_events = week_data["events"]["$ref"]
    
    response3 = requests.get(url=get_events)
    week_games = response3.json()
    week_data_for_dict = {}
    for j in range(len(week_games["items"])):
        game_link = week_games["items"][j]["$ref"]
        response4 = requests.get(url=game_link)
        game = response4.json()
        event_name = game["name"]
        event_date = game["date"]
        event_short_name = ["shortName"]
        if game["competitions"][0]["competitors"][0]["winner"]:
            winner_link = game["competitions"][0]["competitors"][0]["team"]["$ref"]
        else:
            winner_link = game["competitions"][0]["competitors"][1]["team"]["$ref"]
        response5 = requests.get(url=winner_link)
        winner_data = response5.json()
        winner = winner_data["displayName"]
        week_data_for_dict[f"Game {j + 1}"] = {
            "Event Name": event_name,
            "Short Name": event_short_name,
            "Date": event_date,
            "Winner": winner
        }
        print(f"FINISHED FOR GAME {j + 1}/{len(week_games['items'])}")
    data[f"Week {i + 1}"] = week_data_for_dict

print(data)
```

I want to use pandas since i've heard it is the easiest, but if there is a simpler way please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of install pandas, by writing command in your windows powershell or termnal:

```
pip install pandas
```

To use pandas, and convert your  dict into csv format, you should use:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(output)
df.to_csv('espn.csv')
print('okay')
```

I hope it works.